# Find the missing number (number sequence puzzle)

Tags: number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

```
Find the missing number

56784 = 4
11111 = 0
72348 = 3
88652 = 5
88811 = 6
75213 = 0
65465 = 3

62257 = ?
```

I found this quiz in an archive of our company's internal blog. There is no solution provided, nor is there a hint who the author might be. I could not find a solution myself and I am not sure if there is a solution at all.

What I tried (and does not work):

> Multiplying every digit with a factor in the range from -18 to 18 and then take the sum. I did this programmatically, trying out all ~70m combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 62257=1. It's the sum of the number of holes in each digit.